# Interpreting Cascading dot diagrams

Tags: hadoop, cascading

Can someone explain how to read these diagrams? I understand the flow from head to tail, but I am specifically wondering about how to read the field (bracket) transitions between ellipses (Pipes/Taps).

By way of example using the Fields following the Every Pipe in the image, the way I have been able to interpret these is the first Field set i.e. [{2}:'token', 'count'] is what goes into the next Pipe/Tap, but what is the significance of the second Field set [{1}: 'token']?

Is this the field set that went into the previous Pipe above? Is there a programmatic significance to the second bracket i.e. are we able to access it within that pipe with particular Cascading code? (In the case where the second Fields set is greater than the first)

[image: wc Impatient PNG]
<sub>(source: [cascading.org](http://www.cascading.org/files/2012/08/wc.png))</sub>

Comment: There's a more illustrative example of one of these diagrams here: http://www.cascading.org/multitool/

Comment: Thanks that helped me understand other aspects of the diagram. I think Field values may be related to the (kx, Vx) and (Kx list(Vx)) depictions they have on the diagram, but I a struggle to apply it to my understanding above.

Answer (score 2):

The second field set represents which fields are available for subsequent operations in that map or reduce.

In your example above, in the reduce step, since you grouped by 'token', only 'token' is available for subsequent aggregations (Everys) in that reduce step. You could, for example, add another aggregation which output the average token length, but you could not use an aggregation which utilized the 'count' yet.

The reason for this behaviour is that subsequent aggregations on the same group happen in parallel. Thus, the Count won't be completed to feed into any other aggregations you chained on.

Comment: That makes some sense: Would you define the first Fields set (the first bracket) as the fields available for a Tap output and the second Fields set as the fields available for the next operation? If that is the case please update your answer and provide any references you have.